# jquery datepicker is not working while reset the value of datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have included following code in my test.js

```
var refreshRange = function () {
    var tab = $("select[id^='select']").parents("div[id$='_tab']"),
        currentDateSelect = tab.find("select[id^='select'] option:selected")

    if (currentDateSelect.val() != 'range') {
        $("input[name^='start_date']").val('');;
        $("input[name^='end_date']").val('');;
    }
}
```

and in my test.js.erb I have called this

```
refreshRange();
```

Now case is when I select range from `02-02-2015` to `02-03-2015` and when I again go to range and select start_date at that time it allows me to select start_range from `02-03-2015` not from current date and `end_date` is working fine. Please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: Is refreshRange() called once on load, or is it trigger by some action, or something else? How do you configure datepicker, and what version are you using?